# How to get Mobile Identification Number (MIN) in android

Tags: android

Does everybody know how to programmatically get the Mobile Identification Number [(MIN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_identification_number) in android ?

I tried with telephone manager but there is no such thing :

```
TelephonyManager teleManager =   (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

MIN Number looks like below picture :

[image]

Comment: Why would you need this number anyway?

Comment: Because i want to get information like this for quick access Directory.

Comment: I found this on Samsung's website http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000103

Comment: @james : have you found solution for getting MIN ??